# java Xstream custom Converter for Jtree

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I would like to serialize a Jtree to Xml via XStream.

The jTree consists of user objects like this:

```
public class Chapter{

private int id;    
private String iconName;
/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getTitel();
}

/**
 * @return the icon
 */
public String getIcon() {
    return iconName;
}

/**
 * @param icon the icon to set
 */
public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.iconName = icon;
}

}
```

The structure of the Tree looks like that:

```
  root
     +chapter 1
       -chapter 1.1
       -chapter 1.2
           -chapter 1.2.1
    ....
      +chapter 10
```

no i want a XMl String like that:

```
<chapter>
<id>1</id>
  <chapter>
  <id>1</id>
      <chapter>
      <id>1.1</id>
      <chapter>
  <chapter>
  <id>2</id>
  </chapter>
  </chapter>
....
</chapter>
```

How can i do this?
The Xml String don´t need to be deserializable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple tutorial on the Xstream site, https://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html However if I were you, I'd just use JAXB since it is not an external library